# Origen de la expresión 'ni chicha ni limonada'

Tags: historia, españa, hispanoamérica

La expresión 'ni chicha ni limonada' hace referencia a algo o alguien que no sirve para mucho. A primera ojeada lo veía como una comparación entre bebidas (en latinoamérica una chicha es una bebida destilada de maíz y la limonada es la misma en todo el mundo hispano, hasta donde tengo entendido), pero al revisar en el diccionario de la real academia, la expresión viene desde la [primera entrada](https://dle.rae.es/?id=8iTLiDO|8iTzLVT|8iUgK59) (carne comestible).

En Google Ngram muestran la frase desde finales del siglo XIX pero no he podido determinar bien su origen y en particular en donde se originó, pues si surge en hispanoamericana daría un mayor peso a la teoría de las bebidas o si viene desde la península, confirma la expuesta en el DLE (si bien la academia de la lengua cuenta con muchas más fuentes que yo)

Comment: Si la acepción a la que se refiere es la de carne, yo diría que tiene más sentido: si algo no se puede comer ni beber, es que no vale para nada.

Comment: No encuentro ninguna fuente fiable pero hasta ahora lo que he leído indica que hace referencia a las bebidas, una con alcohol de sabor fuerte y otra suave y refrescante por lo que algo que no es "ni chicha ni limonada" sería algo  insulso y mediocre.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pues al final parece que yo estaba equivocado. Me encantan estas cosas del lenguaje, tantos años dando por sentado que algo que no es "ni chicha ni limoná" (como decimos por aquí) es algo que ni se come ni se bebe, y resulta que *chicha* no hacía referencia a la carne sino a un tipo de bebida.

Buscando en el CORDE veo que los casos más antiguos son de Hispanoamérica, como por ejemplo este:

> *Nada hay, pues, que decir sobre esta corrida, que dejándonos muy bien sabor en la primera mitad, en la segunda no fue ni chicha ni limonada.*
>
> Juan Apapucio Corrales, "Crónicas político-doméstico-taurinas", c 1908 - 1930 (Perú).

Hay otro ejemplo que mostaría que su uso es como bebida:

> Chocamos los vasos e invitamos a la muchacha, pero ella dice que sólo bebe chicha y limonada los días de fiesta.
>
> Agustín del Saz, "Panamá y la zona del Canal", 1944 (Panamá).

Y para confirmar ya del todo el origen, acabo de encontrar un artículo en la hemeroteca de la Biblioteca Nacional de España bastante esclarecedor. Aunque se trata de un artículo escrito en Madrid, habla sobre La Habana, y dice lo siguiente:

> El año de 1828 se oyó por primera vez en un barrio estramuros de la Habana, en una choza de gente de color, una canción con el nombre de *guanábana*, que es una fruta de bastante mérito [...]. En 1828 apareció otra en el propio barrio con el de la *limonada*, inventada por los mismos, aludiendo á que se habia concedido el titulo de cabo de ronda á un sujeto que, después de haber admitido brindis de los negros en las bodegas, los perseguía y privaba sus reuniones, y por eso le cantaban que *no era nada, ni chicha, ni limonada*; lo que colocaban de estribillo á todos los versos. Por último en 1843 resonó otra llamada *La lotería* [...].
>
> **El Clamor público.** 26/1/1849, [página 3](http://hemerotecadigital.bne.es/issue.vm?id=0002678608&page=3&search=%22ni%20chicha%20ni%20limonada%22&lang=es).

Por tanto, el origen de la expresión se localiza en una canción de 1828 inventada en La Habana. Pero esta expresión también es muy popular en España, ¿cómo saltó el charco? El mismo artículo lo dice:

> Estas tres canciones que son muy diferentes en su música y objeto, constando cada una de dos partes, las he oído reunidas y formando una solamente muy mal combinada, tanto
>   aqui [Madrid], como en Sevilla y Cádiz; pero nada de esto ha llamado mi atención, ni que aparecieran al cabo de tanto tiempo, sino el nombre que se le ha acomodado de *¡Tango americano!*.

En la segunda mitad del siglo XIX la expresión ya era popular en España y comienza a aparecer incluso en periódicos en la hemeroteca, como este ejemplo:

> Es un hombre que no es hombre
>   como los hombres; no es chicha
>   ni limonada, ni carne
>   ni pescado, [...].
>
> **La Iberia (Madrid).** 15/5/1870, [página 3](http://hemerotecadigital.bne.es/issue.vm?id=0001314635&page=3&search=chicha%20limonada&lang=es).

Entiendo que antes ya sería popular en Hispanoamérica. Entiendo que la difusión de la canción a ambos lados del Atlántico contribuyó a su difusión, junto con el hecho de que la propia canción explicaba su significado y por tanto este se mantuvo invariable.

---

Ya como nota aparte me resulta curioso que la acepción de *chicha* como bebida ya aparece en el *Autoridades* en 1729:

> CHICHA. Bebida hecha de maíz, de que usan en las Indias Occidentales.

En todo caso, en el *Covarrubias* de 1611 solo recoge su acepción como "carne". El *Autoridades* también recoge la siguiente expresión:

> CHICHA Y NABO, ú COSA DE CHICHA Y NABO. Phrase familiár, baxa, con que se explica, que algúna cosa es de poca importancia y despreciable.

Esta expresión hoy día la hemos contraído: *[chichinabo](https://dle.rae.es/?id=8jCSd5e)*, que en contra de lo pueda parecer no tiene nada que ver con las partes pudendas femenina y masculina.

Answer (score 0):

Se refiere a una actitud indefinida, vaga, imprecisa y por lo tanto decepcionante, cuando lo que se espera es firmeza respecto a una de dos posiciones. Ej. -¿Qué opinas de Q?. -Ese tipo, ni chicha ni limonada! Pensaba que nos iba a apoyar y terminó justificando a los otros. Al final todo sigue igual.

Comment: La pregunta es sobre el _origen_ de "ni chicha ni limonada"